# Using IF function in Google Sheets with Negative numbers (e.g -60 or -180)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm confused about this. How can I use an IF Function with negative numbers?

For example if C2 (with a current value of -60) is more than -60, change the value in another cell using IF.

`=IF(C2<=-60,"Send","Not Yet")`

`=IF(C2>-180,"True","False")`

Thanks!

``=IF(C2<=-60,"Send","Not Yet")`

`=IF(C2>-180,"True","False")``

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but if in the cell you want to change, you have the following formula:
`=IF(C2>-60,"Yes","No")`

This cell value will be `Yes` if C2 value is greater than -60 and `No` otherwise
exemple:

- C2 = 0 => 'Yes' in the other cell
- C2 = -70 => `No` in the other cell

I hope that my answer is helpful